# Databases - Tracking Inventory Counts properly

Tags: database, database-design, schema

We get a daily XML file from our supplier with their quantity of stock for each product (a snapshot at that exact moment).

```
1 AM Product A: **500** quantity
2 AM Product A: **400** quantity
3 AM Product A: **350** quantity
4 AM Product A: **550** quantity
```

What is the correct way to model this in a database?

Option A) Inventory Table:

```
1 AM INSERT Product A: 500 quantity
2 AM **UPDATE** Product A: 400 quantity
3 AM **UPDATE** Product A: 350 quantity
4 AM **UPDATE** PRODUCT A: 550 quantity
```

Or, option B) Inventory Table:

```
1 AM INSERT Product A: 500 quantity
2 AM **INSERT** Product A: -100 quantity
3 AM **INSERT** Product A: -50 quantity
4 AM **INSERT** PRODUCT A: +200 quantity
```

The purpose of this database is to store the products that our suppliers carry, and show the inventory to our users, where they are able to purchase these products.

Comment: Option A is easier and faster to query.

Comment: Option B would be suitable for keeping data integrity like when dealing with money transactions.

Comment: Why is B better for keeping data integrity and money?
Are both options acceptable?

Comment: yes, both are acceptable. Money transactions need to be traceable. With option B you can see how the result is being calculated.